# LiipDoctrineCacheBundle how to cache xml?

Tags: symfony, caching

i just wan't to cache xml-content (rss). I have any hour to take this. Caching is configured and still running with other strings. ("Test" or "Hello again")

I'am load the feed with simplexml_load_file. I save the content with json_encode, base64_encode, (array). This will save the content, but if i get fetch the content i became some trouble.

```
private function getRssFeed($url) {
    try {

        $cache_key = $url;
        $cache_driver = $this->container->get('liip_doctrine_cache.ns.mynamespace');

        if ($cache_driver->contains($cache_key)) {
            // How i can the content in original-format?
            return $cache_driver->fetch($cache_key);
        }

        $rssFeed = simplexml_load_file($url);
        $cache_driver->save($cache_key, (array) $rssFeed, strtotime('5 Minutes'));
        //$cache_driver->save($cache_key, json_encode($rssFeed), strtotime('5 Minutes'));
        //$cache_driver->save($cache_key, base64_encode($rssFeed), strtotime('5 Minutes'));
        return $rssFeed;

    } catch(ContextErrorException $e) {
        $this->get('logger')->error('Can not load: '.$url);
        $this->get('logger')->error($e->getCode().' : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Does any can help in this question?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solutions for the problem. *yeah*

It is really simple ;)

```
/**
 * Get a rssfeed
 *
 * Todo: make it better (errorhandling and caching)
 *
 * @param $url
 * @return \SimpleXMLElement
 */
private function getRssFeed($url) {
    try {
        $cache_key = $url;
        $cache_driver = $this->container->get('liip_doctrine_cache.ns.rssfeed');

        if ($cache_driver->contains($cache_key)) {

            return
                simplexml_load_string($cache_driver->fetch($cache_key));
        } else {

            $rssFeed = file_get_contents($url);
            $cache_driver->save($cache_key, $rssFeed, strtotime('5 Minutes'));
            return simplexml_load_string($rssFeed);
        }

    } catch(ContextErrorException $e) {
        $this->get('logger')->error('Can not load: '.$url);
        $this->get('logger')->error($e->getCode().' : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```